# Writing Torah Scroll: Writing a sefer

Tags: jewish-books, sefer-torah, chiddush

The Rambam [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.7.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "It is an affirmative precept binding upon every individual Israelite to write a scroll of the Law for his own use, as it is said, "Now therefore write ye this Song for you" (Deuteronomy 31:19). As the Torah is not written in separate sections, this text means, "Write for yourselves the Torah in which this Song is contained." (Mishneh Torah; Hilchos Sefer Torah 7:1). The Shulchan Aruch [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.270.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "[There is] a Positive Commandment on every Jewish man to copy a Torah Scroll for himself." (Yoreh De'ah 270:2).

I believe the Shach [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.270.5.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that the mitzvah nowadays is fulfilled by writing holy books (please correct me if I'm wrong and the Shach does not say this).

**The question is as follows:** does the mitzvah of  "Therefore, write down this poem and teach it to the people of Israel; put it in their mouths" ([Devarim 31:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.31.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)" means to publicize seforim? Are there any commentators/commentaries that say that the mitzvah is nowadays fulfilled by writing a sefer on a certain Torah-subject? Does one fulfill the mitzvah by writing a book with Torah-insights?

Comment: ספר בתורתו יהגה: ביאור הלכות תלמוד תורה

ומכל שכן מי שזוכה להדפיס ספר דודאי יש בה עכ"פ כמה דברים אמתיים והגהות שונות בתורה הקדושה בספרים שנדפסו כבר ובש"ס אפשר דבזה מקיים ועתה כתבו לכם את השירה 
 הזאת ולמדה את בנ"י לשיטת הרא"ש עכ"ל

(I think that could be a quote from another sefer.)

Comment: I'm confused. Don't you cite already the shach that says this is a mitzva? What else are you looking for?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the Shach says the mitzva is to publish *mishanyos*, *shas* etc.

Comment: Beyond the duplicate question, you should find the following useful: https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/is-there-a-mitzvah-today-to-write-a-sefer-torah/ - https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/724507/rabbi-josh-flug/the-mitzvah-of-writing-a-sefer-torah/ - https://torah.org/learning/mitzvah-18/

Comment: @pcoz: where did you find this quote? It does not show up on Otzar if I try to search it.

Comment: @DoubleAA as what Pcoz writes, I also think the Shach refers to מִשְׁנָה in his explanation to YD 270:5

Comment: @mvs https://bit.ly/3p4XYjP