# Translation request of Likkutei Sichot

Tags: translation, chabad

I do not know if I am allowed to ask this, but is there someone who can help me to translate the [following teaching](https://hebrewbooks.org/14946) of the Lubavitcher Rebbe in his Likkutei Sichos, Shavuos on the topic "the last mitzvah of the Torah, writing a sefer Torah".

Is there someone who can help me to translate these two pages? That would be really appreciated. Footnotes not included.

This question is linked to [my previous post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/127233/27180)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you looked online? There is quite an extensive library here - https://www.sie.org/ and also here - https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/2468546/jewish/Sichos-in-English.htm

Comment: I could not find the translation of this on SIE or on Chabad.org. Only the article called "How We Can Fulfill the Final Mitzvah of the Torah" but I want to understand the original source for that article, and that source is on the two pages I mentioned above.

Comment: https://www.sie.org/templates/sie/article_cdo/aid/2468550/jewish/Sichos-in-English.htm have at it

Comment: @ezra - I sent him there already....

Comment: Thank you. There is a reference to Vol. XXIII, p. 17ff.; Vol. XXIV, p. 207ff of the Likkutei Sichos series. Vol. XXIII, p. 17ff is mentioned in my two screenshots; see above. I couldn't see any translation of these two pages, so my question was if there was somebody who could help me translate it, since I'm starting to learn Hebrew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a summary of the paragraphs:

- Rambam writes [Mishneh Torah Laws of Sefer Torah 7:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.7.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (see link for English translation).
- Question: why do not see everyone striving to fulfil this mitzvah in its fullest form (ie. writing by yourself)?
- Even though one could argue that hiring a competent sofer is better, since the sofer writes nicer.
- And more: we don't say "a mitzvah is better performed by oneself rather than via an agent", unless it looks like you're pushing it off; but here, there's a reason (see previous paragraph), so that doesn't apply.
- These (two previous paragraphs) still don't answer the question, because we don't find that people even work to find a good sofer to hire, or even to correct one letter and make a kosher Torah (upon which it's considered as if it was entirely written by the corrector).
- Simply: the practice is like the Rosh, that the requirement on each person to write a Torah was in past generations, when they used them for study, but now we should write chumashim, mishnayot, gemarot, commentaries, etc. to study, since the mitzvah of writing a Torah is in order to study.
- And this is also the decision of the Shulchan Aruch, who writes the same as the Rosh... (paragraph cut off)

Comment: Thank you very much!